# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

This is an app I am learning to code on, it uses an API to get the weather in certain cities. For some reason the app just dies and I am not able to find out why. The code and the error is as below.

Can anyone help and also if so how did you find the exact error I know the code has said 2 lines where there is errors but this code worked for others using the same lectures as me

the error:

```
5-22 13:10:15.035 10511-10511/com.example.david.whatstheweather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.david.whatstheweather, PID: 10511
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
    at com.example.david.whatstheweather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:135)
    at com.example.david.whatstheweather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:78)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText cityName;
    TextView resultTextView;


    public void findWeather(View view) {

        Log.i("cityName", cityName.getText().toString());

        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cityName.getWindowToken(), 0);

        try {
            String encodedCityName = URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
            task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName + "appid=5cf109a38ccf8138486a2e238847cc0d")


            ;


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        cityName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });


                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {

                String message = "";

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

                Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String main = "";
                    String description = "";

                    main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                    description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                    if (main != "" && description != "") {

                        message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";

                    }

                }

                if (message != "") {

                    resultTextView.setText(message);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }
    }


}
```